# CSS ul li formatting

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

I have been trying to figure out how to put space in between a numbered list and the text and still have the text wrap nicely under the line above it. I found some script on Stack Overflow that works but for some reason I can only get bullets, no numeric's.

Thanks.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50;
}


/* The wider the #list_wrapper is, the more columns will fit in it */

#list_wrapper {
  width: 1000px
}


/* The wider this li is, the fewer columns there will be */

ul.multiple_columns li {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  list-style: decimal;
  height: 30px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <div id="list_wrapper">
      <ul class="column-count: 2;">
        <li>One: If I knew how to spell the ABC's I would write and write and write and write and write and write and write some more and write and write and write and write and write and write and write.</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
        <li>Eight</li>
        <li>Nine</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are trying to select `li` using a class called `multiple_columns` in the `ul`, but you don't have this class in your HTML.

Comment: Azametin.. thanks, I changed "column-count" for multiple columns and got the numbers back. Totolly messes the formatting up though.

Answer (score 0):

Change anything `ul` (unordered list) to `ol` (ordered list).

CSS becomes:

```
ol{
margi... }

ol.multiple_columns li{
    text-align: right;
    float: ri... }
```

HTML becomes:

```
<ol class="column-count: 2;">
<li>One: If I knew ...</li>
<li>Two</li>
...
</ol>
```

In order to make the list numbers bold, but not the text, you would change the `ol` class in your CSS to include `font-weight:900;`:

```
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Then wrap the text of your `<li>` to include `<span style="font-weight:normal;"></span>`, like so:

```
<li><span style="font-weight:normal;">One: If I knew how to spell  ... </span></li>
```

Without the span returning the text to a normal weight, the number and text will both be bold. BTW, `font-weight` ranges from 100-900. `900` is the heaviest weight available.

Comment: Elbrant.. Thank you, that fixed a lot of problems. Is there any way to bold the numbers and make the right column automatically size according to the viewers screen?

Comment: Glad I could help. As far as making the size adjust automatically to the screen size... you would have to change your width settings from `px` to `%`. Play with it a bit.